# Powerbroker domain profile identical to local profile so no folder created

Tags: login

I log into my Ubuntu 14.04 as my local user "dan". I just used Powerbroker to join it to my domain, but it doesn't create a new profile when I log in as my domain user, which also happens to be "dan", because the folder dan already exists. I removed the part where the login assumes the default domain `sudo /opt/pbis/bin/config AssumeDefaultDomain true`, so I'm forced to log in as domain\dan -- thinking it would create a folder in my home directory as domain.dan or domain\dan -- similar to how Windoze does it, but it still logs into my local/original user "dan" even if I log in as domain\dan.

I renamed my existing `/home/dan` to `dan-old`, and I can now log in as my domain user, so I am wondering how to make it so Powerbroker creates a special kind of "domain" folder in my home directory. I believe when I set it up, I used the following command `sudo /opt/pbis/bin/config HomeDirTemplate %H/%U` to create the home folders. Can I add another variable so it appends something to the home folder so I can differentiate between a local user and domain user? Maybe `%H/%U-%domain` (where `%domain` is my netbios domain name -- of course, that variable is just made up).

If there is an easier way to do this I would appreciate anyone's know-how. I will be adding MANY Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 computers to the domain, and currently they all log in with usernames that match their Windows Active Directory domain name so I'd rather do it right the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I just left out:

```
/opt/pbis/bin/config HomeDirTemplate %H/%U
```

and instead of creating a folder (or trying to and failing because it already exists) in `/home/dan`, it creates folders such as:

```
/home/local/domain/dan
```

Perfect actually! :)

Answer (score 1):

after setting up AD for Windows clients we decided to also allow for Linux clients.

So we created a folder "userhomes" on our server which we exported to the network as nfs.
We then created "new" home folders, where each user stored his home directory. 
This is at least a bit like roaming profiles.

Just install nfs on your server with:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

then create a folder, where you store the home directories:

```
sudo mkdir /userhomes
```

and then edit /etc/exports like this (where you replace the IP with your network):

```
"/userhomes/" 192.168.178.0/255.255.255.0(rw,async,no_root_squash,insecure)
```

Finally just restart nfs-kernel-server, to have the folder exported to the network.

```
sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

On the client side, als local root user mount the networkfolder on boot time:

First, install nfs-common:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

second, change /etc/fstab, to mount the folder once the machine starts:

```
pdc.mydomain.lan:/userhomes /home/local/mydomain nfs rw 0 0
```

(change your domain name, server and folder names accordingly)

the last thing to do is to make and initially mount the folder for it to work in future:

```
sudo mkdir /home/local/mydomain && mount /home/local/mydomain
```

last but not least tell PBIS to change the home directory template!!!

```
sudo /opt/pbis/bin/config HomeDirTemplate %H/local/%D/%U
```

**That's it!!**

This will cause your machine to:

1. load network files system of your pdc on boot time
2. store home folders of your users on the server accordingly.

Hope this is of help, even if only for ohters.. ;)